# How to generate a PDF with tabular data from SQLite along with a few images?

Tags: ios, sqlite, pdf

I have a table in SQLlite on my iPad app. When the user clicks a button "Print" i want to call a method which would read the table and create a PDF file with the table data. Also want to add the company logo and address on top.

Any idea how this can be done? I'm a beginner in iOS programming and hence do not know where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is it like that you are showing preview before converting it to pdf or print ?

Comment: No there is no preview. I display the data in a UITableView but that is not i want to print. The format that needs to go into the PDF is different and needs to be pulled directly from the sqlite table and written to the PDF, which then is to be sent via email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently been working on an app which required PDFs to be produced for emailing/printing.

For this I used [NDHTMLtoPDF](https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf) which as its name suggests generates a PDF from HTML. To accomplish the HTML generating I have a base HTML template in the apps main bundle which has custom tags such as {content} which I can then replace with whatever I want within my class by using

> stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{content}" withString:MY_HTML_STRING

so, within your base HTML file you would already have the company logo and address set as well as the relevant table tags.

I appreciate you are new to iOS Programming, so I suggest you look into the NSString methods available for adding and replacing strings.

**Update:**

First you need to get your baseHtml file into a NSString:

```
NSString *htmlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"base" ofType:@"html"];
```

As mentioned, the HTML file would already have tags to place the company logo and address in the required positions on the page.

You would then have HTML tags which produces a table, which would be designed based on how you want your model data to be displayed.

Within the table, you would have various placeholder tags which I usually enclose in {}, however you can use <> or whatever you like, which you would use to populate with your model data.

So, say you had an attribute in your model which was firstName, you would place {firstName} in one of the cells within a HTML table cell.

Then back in the class where you are generating your HTML, you would do:

```
htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{firstName}" withString:[YOUR_MODEL firstName]];
```

You would then do that for each of the data model objects you wish to display in the PDF.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of using an HTML template as well but was wondering if there is a method available to generate html for the table data. did a lot of searching but appears like i'll have to write it from the scratch. Can you share the method u send in your app to do this, I could probably build on top of that if they are on the same lines

Comment: I don't use a single method, the class I am using has 20 methods in it.  I will update my answer with some suggestions as to how to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks Nick... That will really help.

Comment: I was able to generate the PDF using NDHTMLtoPDF using html stirng. I think I'll write another method to generate the HTML from scratch. Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: Hi nick, I am creating pdf in xcode and i did all static things now i want to add javascript function result from html page to pdf in front of static labels can you please help me to solve this issue.